# My flagging was disputed and the same question marked as flag

Tags: support, disputed-flags

I flagged a question as "too board", within some minutes its marked as "disputed". I just thought my flagging was invalid or not correct. After some time I check back on the question and see it was put on hold as "too board". I'm confused, what do I have to do?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57550658/how-to-remove-the-vendor-text-that-shows-up-in-checkout-page-of-woocommerce) is the link to the question.

And these are my flags:

> [image]

Comment: Probably a dispute in review, but it was closed from outside the queue. Doesn't change your flag response, but disputed flags don't affect you negatively

Comment: We need the exact time of your flag but my guess is that your flag caused the Triage review and that outcome was Looks OK, disputing your flag: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57550658/timeline

Comment: @Zoe Thanks for the response . But Can anyone change the disputed to helpful.

Comment: No, flag outcomes don't become helpful once disputed.

Comment: @rene Please check my screenshot it shows how many hours ago only. How do I get the exact time?

Comment: Hover over the time, the tooltip will give you the UTC time

Comment: Please check the question it put into hold from the last 45 minutes only and I flagged 1 hour ago. And now my flagging page showing 2 hours ago

Comment: I linked you to the timeline, it has the timings in UTC as well but there are 3 reviews in the timeline. To reason about the order of events your rough estimate is not good enough

Comment: Here are the screenshots. Please check it https://imgur.com/a/biRW4oa , https://imgur.com/2QKBgyQ

Comment: Those would only be useful if the tooltip was showing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU8fJ.png ...

Comment: I can confirm the disputed outcome was due to the triage review (simultaneous timestamps).

Comment: Just move on. All your flags don't have to be marked as helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the same question marked as flag"*?

Comment: The question I tagged flag is disputed and the same question marked as flag.